# Write a command that finds all empty files and directories in the current directory and all sub-directories

Tags: command-line

Write a command that finds all empty files and directories in the current directory and all sub-directories.

Only the names of the files and directories should be displayed (not the entire path)
Hidden files should be listed
One file name per line
The listing should end with a new line
You are not allowed to use basename, grep, egrep, fgrep or rgrep

Comment: Please, have some respect for the community and don't copy/paste a homework assignment ... At least put some effort in rewriting it.

Answer (score 1):

List **regular empty files** withouth path (2 possibilities):

```
find /mypath/mydir -size 0 -type f | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'

find /mypath/mydir -empty  -type f | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'
```

Use sudo, if some files or subfolders are not accessible for present user.

```
sudo find /mypath/mydir -size 0 -type f | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'
```

List **empty folders** withouth path:

```
sudo find /mypath/mydir -empty -type d | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }'
```

### Edit

Using Raffa's suggestion:

Files

```
find /mypath/mydir -size 0 -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

Directories:

```
find /mypath/mydir -empty -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: Instead of piping to AWK, you can use `find`'s own action `-printf '%f\n'`